# Having trouble understanding relationship between a cone and its dual

Tags: linear-algebra

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiHL8.png) in proof for 2.) of Lemma 1.12. I do not understand how part 1.) implies that $C = D^*$. Namely, why is the dual of the set of row vectors the set of vectors part of a cone? The page is part of Polyhedral Geometry and Linear Optimization Summer Semester 2010 by Andreas Paffenholz.